# Animate Android app launched from Service

Tags: android, android-animation

I am launching an activity from a `Service` using the normal pattern:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I want to **animate** that launch e.g. slide in from left.

From an `Activity`, you can use [Activity.overridePendingTransition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29).

---

Is there a way to animate an activity launch from a `Service`?

Comment: A workaround would be to launch an invisible activity, that in turn launches what I want to show. But this adds a slight delay to the process.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the workaround of placing my own activity into the launch process.

My `Service` launches my `HelperActivity` with extras in the intent identifying the task I wish to launch/bring to front.

`HelperActivity` launches the actual task in `onCreate()`, animating the change with `overridePendingTransition()`. Then calls `finish()` in order to remain hidden.

Obviously `HelperActivity` needs to remain hidden from the backstack, so the manifest reflects this.

---

There are also security concerns to this naive method - see related post by Commonsware:

- [Beware Accidental APIs](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/09/11/beware-accidental-apis-avoid-intents-extras.html)

This type of activity should be as secure as possible. For my demo version, I'm happy to just set `android:exported="false"`.

---

Manifest Code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SwitchAnimationHelperActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
```

---

HelperActivity Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String componentName = getIntent().getStringExtra("TASK_ID_API");
    Intent newTask = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    newTask.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    newTask.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(componentName));
    startActivity(newTask);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_zoom_in, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);

    // job is done
    finish();
}
```

---

So there it is - one way to animate the launch of a task from a `Service`.